# Point System Query

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

Can someone please explain to me how the point system works?

For many upvotes I get nothing, for some I get +2, for some comment upvotes I get nothing.... for other upvotes I get +10.

What is the method behind this madness? I seem to have been stuck around 1960 for a while now...

Comment: Comment upvotes never give reputation. Answer upvoted give $+10$, with a cap of $+200$ per day; once you reach this cap, you won't receive more reputation from upvotes. Answer accepts give $+15$, independent of the cap. Looking at your [reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/142299/notnotlogical?tab=reputation), this seems to account for everything; there are a few downvotes (giving $-2$) and unaccepts (removing the $+15$), as well as $-350$ from some bounties.

Comment: See also [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) on meta.SE.

Comment: I see, thank you. BTW, what's up with the unaccepts? I got a few "accepts then unaccepts", and I also got an "upvote then unupvote". ????? Tell people to make their mind up.

Comment: Voting on SE is weird sometimes. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The authoritative explanation of the reputation system.](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)